# Loop in my msgbox - Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems with the following code :

```
Sub Option_choice()

Dim Choice_box As String

Do
Choice_box = InputBox("Quel état souhaitez-vous restituer ?" & _
     vbCrLf & "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3" & _
     vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Bilan" & _
     vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Compte de résultat" & _
     vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Hors bilan", vbQuestion, "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3")

Select Case Choice_box
 Case "1"
     MsgBox ("Bilan")
 Case "2"
     MsgBox ("Compte de résultat")
 Case "3"
     MsgBox ("Hors bilan")
 Case Else
     MsgBox "Vous devez sélectionner une valeur égale à 1, 2 ou 3" & _
     vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Désirez-vous continuer ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Erreur"

        If vbYes Then
           Loop
        ElseIf vbNo Then
           MsgBox "Fin de l'opération, aucun état n'a été généré", vbInformation, "Fin du programme"
        Else
         'rien
        End If
End Select

End Sub
```

I would just like to repeat the `MsgBox` from the beginning when the answer of the following question is `NO`:

```
MsgBox "Vous devez sélectionner une valeur égale à 1, 2 ou 3" & _
         vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Désirez-vous continuer ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Erreur"
```

It says:

> "Error Loop without Do"

Could you help please?

Thanks,

Jean

Comment: You cannot have interleaved blocks in vba. Your `Loop`must be after the `End Select` and you can use an `Exit Do` in the `vbNo` branch to exit the loop if needed.

Comment: Note that you are not retrieving the return value of the MsgBox and testing constants in your following `If ... ElseIf` sentences.

Comment: @VincentG I've updated my code and set a variable for my answer (VbYesNo).

Comment: Now the thing is when I click CANCEL on my first input box, it doesn't exit... I don't know how to escape from it. i've added a case "If vbcancel then Exit Do" but it does not work

Comment: Your edition doesn't appears and vbYesNo is a constant from vba, you shouldn't use is as a name for a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to start a loop that will only end once the condition is satisfied.

Try the below:

```
Sub Option_choice()

Dim Choice_box As String
Do
    Choice_box = InputBox("Quel état souhaitez-vous restituer ?" & _
         vbCrLf & "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3" & _
         vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Bilan" & _
         vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Compte de résultat" & _
         vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Hors bilan", vbQuestion, "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3")

    Select Case Choice_box
     Case "1"
         MsgBox ("Bilan")
         Exit Do
     Case "2"
         MsgBox ("Compte de résultat")
         Exit Do
     Case "3"
         MsgBox ("Hors bilan")
         Exit Do
     Case Else
         If MsgBox("Vous devez sélectionner une valeur égale à 1, 2 ou 3" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Désirez-vous continuer ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Erreur") = vbYes Then
                'Nothing, it will loop anyway
            ElseIf vbNo Then
               MsgBox "Fin de l'opération, aucun état n'a été généré", vbInformation, "Fin du programme"
               Exit Sub
            End If
    End Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: ComboBox is not defined, and not affected inside the `Do While ... Loop`, so is useless. A `Do... Loop` without condition does the same.

Comment: @VincentG "Useless" is not the right word in this case, it does a pretty clear job, but I concede that Do is better here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for helping, here's my final code for those who need it.

```
Sub Option_choice()

 Dim Choice_box, File_Choice As String
 Dim Rep_Choice As Integer

Do
    Choice_box = InputBox("Quel état souhaitez-vous restituer ?" & _
     vbCrLf & "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3" & _
     vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Bilan" & _
     vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Compte de résultat" & _
     vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Hors bilan", vbQuestion, "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3")

Select Case Choice_box
    Case "" 'if cancelled
        MsgBox "Fin de l'opération, aucun état n'a été généré", vbInformation, "Fin du programme"
        Exit Sub
    Case "1"
        MsgBox ("Bilan")
        File_Choice = "Bilan"
        MsgBox ("Filechoice = " & File_Choice)
        Exit Do
    Case "2"
        MsgBox ("Compte de résultat")
        File_Choice = "Compte de résultat"
        MsgBox ("Filechoice = " & File_Choice)
        Exit Do
    Case "3"
        MsgBox ("Hors bilan")
        File_Choice = "Hors bilan"
        MsgBox ("Filechoice = " & File_Choice)
        Exit Do
    Case Else
        Rep_Choice = MsgBox("Vous devez sélectionner une valeur égale à 1, 2 ou 3" & _
        vbCrLf & "Désirez-vous continuer ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Erreur")
            If Rep_Choice = vbNo Then
                MsgBox "Fin de l'opération, aucun état n'a été généré", vbInformation, "Fin du programme"
                Exit Do
            Else
                'loop
            End If
End Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Jean

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Option_choice()

    Dim Choice_box As String
    Dim MB_result As Integer

    Do
        Choice_box = InputBox("Quel état souhaitez-vous restituer ?" & _
             vbCrLf & "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3" & _
             vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & "1 - Bilan" & _
             vbCrLf & vbTab & "2 - Compte de résultat" & _
             vbCrLf & vbTab & "3 - Hors bilan", vbQuestion, "Entrez la valeur 1, 2 ou 3")

        Select Case Choice_box
            Case "1"
                MsgBox ("Bilan")
            Case "2"
                MsgBox ("Compte de résultat")
            Case "3"
                MsgBox ("Hors bilan")
            Case Else
                MB_result = MsgBox("Vous devez sélectionner une valeur égale à 1, 2 ou 3" & _
                    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Désirez-vous continuer ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Erreur")

                If MB_result = vbNo Then
                   MsgBox "Fin de l'opération, aucun état n'a été généré", vbInformation, "Fin du programme"
                   Exit Do
                End If
        End Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Just as a small point, this won't exit the loop after 1, 2 or 3 is selected

Comment: @tompreston The original code wasn't exiting the loop either, and I didn't known the requirements, maybe the user wants to be asked in sequence.